# Given a row with a list too big to explode(), how do I do a preparatory explode() to bring list size down to fit into memory?

Tags: list, explode, python-polars

I'm trying to do an `.explode` on a column, and stream or sink to file, but one of the lists has 300k items (6.7mil characters if combined into a string).

```py
import polars as pl

test = pl.LazyFrame({'col1': 'string '*1_000_000})
(test
 .with_columns(explode_me = pl.col('col1').str.split(' '))
 .explode(pl.col('explode_me'))
 .collect(streaming=True)
 .write_parquet('file.parquet')
)
```

[This issue](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9520) was created, but "a single row explodes to more than fits into memory. There is not much what we can do with the current architecture. At absolute minimum, the explosion of a single row should fit."

How do I best split the oversized lists into lists with fewer items so my later `.explode` will fit into memory? (possibily using `pl.when()`)

Basically, split the string every 50k words so I can explode to 6 rows, so I can then later explode 6 rows of 50k, instead of 1 row of 300k (which overloads memory).

EDIT:
My current solution

```py
import polars as pl

test = pl.LazyFrame({'col1': 'string '*1_000_000})
(test
 .with_columns(explode_me = pl.col('col1').str.split(' '))
 .with_columns(
     pl.col('explode_me').apply(lambda x: [x[i:i+10_000] for i in range(0, len(x), 10_000)], 
                                return_dtype= pl.List(pl.List(pl.Utf8))) 
  )
 .select(pl.col('explode_me'))
 .explode(pl.col('explode_me'))
 .sink_parquet('file.parquet')
)
```

Comment: Your current approach raises `ComputeError: The output type of 'apply' function cannot determined` - why not set the `return_dtype`? `pl.apply(..., return_dtype=pl.List(pl.List(pl.Utf8)))` works in streaming for me. Although I imagine there is a proper way to do this without apply.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I always seem to forget about that piece. And agreed, I'd love to not use the `.apply`

Comment: Okay, so that gets rid of the exception, but just to confirm: does it actually run your use-case without overloading memory?

Comment: Welp, last night's rest seemed to fix the issues I was having, so now yes!

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Now to try figure out how to do it without apply.

Comment: I've added a follow-up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76628658/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `list.slice` method to chunk the list into smaller lists. The below takes your example (with only 10 strings) and chunks them into 5 columns of lists of two strings. I save the chunk names and expressions in the chunk_cols so you can set the chunking logic at run time with whatever logic you want.

```py
chunk_cols = {f'chunk{i}': pl.col('explode_me').list.slice(2*i, 2) for i in range(5)}

test = pl.LazyFrame({'col1': ' '.join([f'string_{i}' for i in range (10)])})
(test
 .with_columns(explode_me = pl.col('col1').str.split(' '))
 .with_columns(
     **chunk_cols
 )
 .explode(pl.col('chunk1'))
 .collect(streaming=True)
 .select('col1','chunk1')
)

col1                chunk1
str                 str
"string_0 strin…    "string_2"
"string_0 strin…    "string_3"
```

Comment: My goal is to keep it all in one column (or a single additional created column) instead of creating numerous additional columns that need to be later combined. It would be only applied to columns with strings over a certain length, are you able to accomplish it in more of a `.explode`-chaining way?
I do think the `.slice` is on the right track.