# How do I encapsulate an element into list without using an `.apply` in Polars?

Tags: list, explode, python-polars

A follow-on from my question about [preparatory `.explode` for rows too big for regular explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76564658/)

How do I appropriately encapsulate a list into another list without using an `.apply`?

I only want to use the slow `.apply` on the one or two rows which necessitate it by being too large for a regular explode.
But when I try to use `.when`/`.then`, I don't know what to put in place of the `None` below to overcome the mismatch between the normal value `pl.List(pl.Utf8)` and prep'd `pl.List(pl.List(pl.Utf8)` (for the double `.explode` later).

Ideally, it'd be something like `list(pl.col('explode_me'))`

This works:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.LazyFrame({'col1': ['string '*1_000_000, 'a b c']})
(df
 .with_columns(explode_me = pl.col('col1').str.split(' '))
 .with_columns(
     (pl.when(pl.col('explode_me').list.lengths() <= 4)
        .then(None)
        .otherwise(pl.col('explode_me').apply(lambda x: [x[i:i+10_000] for i in range(0, len(x), 10_000)]), 
                                              return_dtype= pl.List(pl.List(pl.Utf8)))))
 .explode('explode_me').explode('explode_me')
 .collect(streaming=True)
)
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't for the life of me get it to work.
I've tried fiddling with concat, pl.List, implode, cast...

Comment: your df definition doesn't work so I can't see what the rest of it is supposed to do.

Comment: Copying error, forgot to add the brackets around the list, should be corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution, which may be a bit roundabout because I split the columns, and then coalesce them back together once they're the same type:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.LazyFrame({'col1': ['string '*1_000_000, 'a b c']})
(df
 .with_columns(explode_me = pl.col('col1').str.split(' '))
 .with_columns(part1 = (pl.when(pl.col('explode_me').list.lengths() >= 4)
                          .then(pl.col('explode_me').apply(lambda x: [x[i:i+10_000] for i in range(0, len(x), 10_000)], 
                                                           return_dtype= pl.List(pl.List(pl.Utf8))))),
               part2 = (pl.when(pl.col('explode_me').list.lengths() <= 4)
                          .then(pl.col('explode_me'))),
               )
.explode('part1')
.with_columns(pl.coalesce(['part1', 'part2']).alias('combined'))
.select('combined')
.explode('combined')
.collect(streaming=True)
)
```